# handling dynamic excel sheets

Tags: c#, excel, dynamic, ssis

I am having a case in which I need to import an excel file,having two sheets into the DB. I am using a SSIS package for the same. The issue is,I can make the excel sheet dynamic,by setting the expressions but the sheets into the excel workbook are also changing names. How can I also  get to make the sheet names more dynamic.
I have tried using Microsoft.Office.InterOp.excel in my DEV code,but the PROD does not have excel installed on it. Can somebody resolve this for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something similar to the script below, which can be found at [Code Spot - Dynamic Sheet Name in SSIS Excel Spreadsheet Imports](http://codespot.blogspot.com/2011/01/dynamic-sheet-name-in-ssis-excel.html). It doesn't require Excel to be installed on the machine.

```
string excelFile = null;
string connectionString = null;
OleDbConnection excelConnection = null;
DataTable tablesInFile = null;
int tableCount = 0;
DataRow tableInFile = null;
string currentTable = null;
int tableIndex = 0;
string[] excelTables = null;

excelFile = Dts.Variables["User::ExcelFile"].Value.ToString();

connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + excelFile + ";Extended Properties=Excel 8.0";

excelConnection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

excelConnection.Open();
tablesInFile = excelConnection.GetSchema("Tables");

tableCount = tablesInFile.Rows.Count;
excelTables = new string[tableCount];

foreach (DataRow tableInFile_loopVariable in tablesInFile.Rows)
{
tableInFile = tableInFile_loopVariable;
currentTable = tableInFile["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
excelTables[tableIndex] = currentTable;
tableIndex += 1;
}
}

Dts.Variables["User::SheetName"].Value = excelTables[0];

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SQL script to load the the Excel file as it is to a staging table, from there it's processed using SSIS / T-SQL, it's relatively fast and reliable. You can download the driver by itself, you don't need office installation to use this method.

```
/*Drop table if exists*/
IF OBJECT_ID(’table_1', 'U') IS NOT NULL
EXEC ('DROP TABLE table_1')

/*Load using access driver, can probably work with excel too.*/
select *
into [table_1]
from openrowset('MSDASQL'
               ,'Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)}'
               ,'select * from 'D:\folder\file.csv' ')
```